# Who is this goblin with a teapot on a stick?

Tags: character-identification, toys

I'm trying to identify this action figure.  It is only labeled "Electronic Arts", leading me to assume it is related to a video game.

[image: goblin-1]

[image: goblin-2]

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It's the Mad Hatter from [*American McGee's Alice*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_McGee%27s_Alice), although the one you have is missing the magnificent hat.

[image]

<sup>I'm pretty sure this picture is actually from *Madness Returns*, the sequel; the character design is the same in both games, but in *Alice* he doesn't have the bruising around his eyes</sup>

[image]

The action figure comes in two variants; the one you have appears to be the "White jacket" variant:

[image]

Comment: good answer.  It's a lot harder with the hat missing!

Comment: Such a creepy game. Never played it the whole way through (saw it at a friend's house), but I was very impressed with how thoroughly they nailed the vibe

Comment: @KRyan I've never played it either, but I always wanted to. Alas, it's not on Steam, and I'll be damned if I'm inflicting Origin upon my laptop

Comment: @JasonBaker Not on Steam? http://store.steampowered.com/app/19680/

Comment: Or do you mean the first part? It seems to be available as abandonware, e.g. [here](http://www.myabandonware.com/game/american-mcgee-s-alice-452), but of course IANAL to judge that claim...

Comment: @Zommuter Yeah, I wanted the first one; I'm a bit compulsive about watching things in order. Cheers for the link, though. I was sure EA was still selling it on Origin, but I may have to check into that more thoroughly